# Показать картинку на одну секунду java

Tags: android, java

Собственно вопрос находится в названии. Нужно каким-то образом показать картинку на долю секунды. Никто не подскажет как это сделать на java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int nm;
Timer tm=new Timer(1000,new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent pdj)
        {
            nm+=1;
            if(nm==2) // установить на какой секунде будет показываться картинка
            {
                ...//тут написать код отрисовывающий картинку
            }
        }
    }
);
tm.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (--life < 1) {
      temps.remove(this);
}
```